# Automatically calculate the date oracle APEX

Tags: oracle, date, apex, computation

how can the date be calculated depending on the input of a user?
That is, depending on what the user enters, 3 months will be added to the current date or 5, etc.

I tried to add a computation to the date pickers:

- SUBMISSION_DATE displays only the current date (already implemented)
- DATE_OF_ISSUE should be SUBMISSION_DATE +3months or +5months, depending on users input in another field.

I added as well a computation to this date with the following pl/sql function body, but it is not working.

```
DECLARE
sub_date DATE default null;
BEGIN
if :P75_THESISTYPE =1
then 
sub_date := :P75_SUBMISSION_DATE +6;
else
sub_date := :P75_SUBMISSION_DATE +3;
END IF;
return sub_date;
end;
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?  Raising an error?  Or doing what?  This computation will be performed on page submit so you will not see the result of it until after that.

Comment: what I actually want is that depending on the choice of the user, the submission date will be set automatically, so that a certain number of months is added to the current date and this is then the result for the submission date.

Comment: And what actually happens?

Comment: When using the above mentioned pl/sql function body I get this errror: 
ORA-06550: line 6, column 13: PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type ORA-06550: line 6, column 1: PL/SQL: Statement ignored ORA-06550: line 8, column 13: PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type ORA-06550: line 8, column 1: PL/SQL: Statement ignored

Comment: Thank you - now I can answer the question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@TonyAndrews has the correct process, but as he followed your initial statement, it will not give the desired result. Adding an integer to a data add that *number of days* not months. What you need is the ADD_Months function; So:

```
DECLARE
  sub_date DATE default null;
BEGIN
  if :P75_THESISTYPE =1
  then 
    sub_date := add_months(to_date(:P75_SUBMISSION_DATE),6);
  else
    sub_date := add_months(to_date(:P75_SUBMISSION_DATE),3);
  end if
  return sub_date;
end;
/
```

Of course the above assumes your variable's format matches your nls_data_format. Generally a dangerous assumption at best,

Answer (score 1):

The page items are treated as VARCHAR2 so you need to convert them to dates before performing arithmetic on them:

```
DECLARE
  sub_date DATE default null;
BEGIN
  if :P75_THESISTYPE =1
  then 
    sub_date := TO_DATE(:P75_SUBMISSION_DATE) +6;
  else
    sub_date := TO_DATE(:P75_SUBMISSION_DATE) +3;
  END IF;
  return sub_date;
end;
/
```